# How to check the sting is alphanumeric or not in peggyjs

Tags: javascript, regex, alphanumeric

I want to check the given string is alphanumeric or not. i.e. the expected output is as follows

- `123` should retun false
- `abc` should retun false
- `a123` should retun true
- `1a23` should retun true

I tried with the `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` regex. It is not working as expected. Can anyone suggest the working `peggyjs` regex? Thanks.

Comment: Try this: [`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/bwpppz/1)

Comment: Getting this error `peg$SyntaxError: Expected "!", "$", "&", "(", ".", "@", character class, comment, end of line, identifier, literal, or whitespace but "?" found.` Can you give the solution for this? Thanks

Comment: How about this? [`^[0-9]+[a-zaA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$|^[a-zaA-Z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/bwpppz/2)

Comment: Different error `peg$SyntaxError: Expected "!", "$", "&", "(", ".", character class, comment, end of line, identifier, literal, or whitespace but "^" found.`

Comment: @BenkI Did you look at the examples how to implement this? https://github.com/peggyjs/peggy/tree/main/examples or perhaps the readme?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I have looked at it, but I didn't get it. So I have posted the question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can assert not only digits, and match at least a single digit restricticting to match to only a-z or a digit.

Using a case insensitive match:

```
^(?!\d+$)[a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YXaRTj/1)

Comment: Getting this error `peg$SyntaxError: Expected "!", "$", "&", "(", ".", character class, comment, end of line, identifier, literal, or whitespace but "^" found.` Can you give the solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: @BenkI I am currenly on a mobile device and not able to test the peggy software. Perhaps if you update your question with what you have tried, it will be clearer to what kind of a solution you are looking for. Currently it is closed as for the regex solution there is a duplicate answer found.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the order (letters then numbers for example) you can do `.*[a-zA-Z].*[0-9]`

But I assume you can't make such assumptions so I would use the slightly more complex `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*` which means "a letter somewhere later, and also a number somewhere later".

PS : you can replace all `[0-9]` by `\d` if you like.

Edit : that's only assuming you don't get other kinds of characters, use Alireza's regex instead if you need to.

Comment: Getting this error `peg$SyntaxError: Expected "!", "$", "&", "(", ".", character class, comment, end of line, identifier, literal, or whitespace but "^" found.` Can you give the solution for this? Thanks